# Web Audio API, manipulating nodes

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

If I want to change the stereo *panner* value while the sound is already playing, What is the proper way?

As I understand the nodes are fire-and-forget, so I shouldn't keep a reference to them in my code, so they can be garbage collected. But when I don't have reference to the source node I can't modify it later.

Do I have to start holding references in arrays, watch for when they are done and implement my own node cleaning, or is there a more clean way to get access to them once I run them?

I expected some kind of `getActiveNodes` method from `Audio Context`, but that is apparently not a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a function somewhere in your code which plays an `AudioBufferSourceNode` and also creates a `StereoPannerNode`. Maybe it looks somehow like this:

```
function playAudioBuffer (audioContext, audioBuffer) {
    const audioBufferSourceNode = new AudioBufferSourceNode(audioContext, { buffer: audioBuffer });
    const sterePannerNode = new StereoPannerNode(audioContext);

    audioBufferSourceNode
        .connect(sterePannerNode)
        .connect(audioContext.destination);

    audioBufferSourceNode.start();
}
```

You could define a variable which is accessible inside that function and holds a reference to all active AudioNodes.

```
const activeAudioNodes = [ ];
```

It's just an array. You could use the `ended` event that gets fired by an `AudioBufferSourceNode` to manage it. Your `playAudioBuffer()` function would then look like this:

```
function playAudioBuffer (audioContext, audioBuffer) {
    const audioBufferSourceNode = new AudioBufferSourceNode(audioContext, { buffer: audioBuffer });
    const sterePannerNode = new StereoPannerNode(audioContext);

    audioBufferSourceNode
        .connect(sterePannerNode)
        .connect(audioContext.destination);

    audioBufferSourceNode.start();

    const audioNodes = { audioBufferSourceNode, sterePannerNode };

    activeAudioNodes.push(audioNodes);

    audioBufferSourceNode.onended = () => {
        audioBufferSourceNode.disconnect();
        sterePannerNode.disconnect();

        activeAudioNodes.splice(activeAudioNodes.indexOf(audioNodes), 1);
    };
}
```

The `activeAudioNodes` array will then hold a reference to each playing `AudioNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to change them in the future, theres nothing wrong with storing your elements in an array or in individual variables. You can do this when you create the element or simply select all of them using `document.querySelect`, etc. For example you can select all `<audio>` elements with this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('audio') // NodeList
```

I am not exactly sure what you would like to do with these elements (as there is a lot of functionality within the API) so I will link you to the MDN [documentation for the Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). It may also be useful to look at [`<audio>` element docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) also.

Comment: I don't use <audio> elements, I am fetching audio buffers. My point was, when I have a chain, e.g. sourceNode -> gainNode -> panNode -> convolverNode -> masterGainNode -> output, according to specification, they are garbage collected when the sound stops playing, but if I store them in an array I will create reference that will keep all those nods in memory. After 1 hour of playing a web game, thousands of nodes were created, and memory is a mess. Deleting them manually from array is problematic. When I am using echo effect I don't know when the echo is finished for example.